# Add line break inside string only between specific position and only if there is a white space - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very long string that I'm exporting to excel. I would like to add line break where there is a white space after **each** 45 char's.

For example:
Line break after the **6th** char:

"This is an example for short string"

"This is
An example
short string"

I'm not a regex expert but until now I came up white this, but it's breaking the line no matter if there is a white space on the 45th char

```
resultString += `${text.match(/.{1,44}/g).join('\n')} \n \n`;
```

Comment: rough idea : break the string on the space character (split), loop through the array of words (the split call will give you an array of words), sum the number of characters in each array value, and when it's more then 45, you know you have to break on the previous word. Regexp won't do any good here

Comment: You description says **each** character, but your example shows only one (the first 6th). Which is it? And what would happen if your example contained another space and word?

Comment: @vol7ron I edited the example, sorry abou that

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace and replacer function with conditional replace values.

Here i am matching values upto 45 character and checking if the next character is space or not ( which is captured in capturing group g1 ). Based on `g1` we return value from replacer function

```js
let str = `Line break after the 6th char:

"This is an example"`


let str2 = `Line break after the 6th char:

"This is an e xample"`

let spliter = (str) =>
  str.replace(/[\s\S]{1,45}(.)/g, (match, g1) =>
    g1 === ' ' ? `${match}\n` : match
  )


console.log(spliter(str))
console.log(spliter(str2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used that in the end:

```
        const arrayFromString: string[] = string.split('');
        let index = 0;
        arrayFromString.forEach((char: string) => {
          index++;
          if (index > 45 && char === ' ') {
            resultsText += '\n    ';
            index = 0;
          } else {
            resultsText += char;
          }
```